# How to refer to another workbook/worksheet dynamically in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic

Currently I am trying to link to another workbook/worksheet using dynamic range;
i.e. using `ADDRESS(some function)` to get a range (eg. $A1:$C10)
then linking it to another workbook.

Eg. On Worksheet 1:
`='Worksheet2'!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(function A):ADDRESS(function B))`
but it returns error.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

I know using VBA is a simpler solution but my colleagues are unable to use VBA (I'm currently in finance) so I'm trying to make it as "excel" as possible

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try writing the worksheets's name into the indirect function? `=INDIRECT("'Worksheet2'!"&ADDRESS... )`

Comment: This works but I was hoping for more succinct method; I guess my option is limited when I'm using excel functions